# How to loading specific no of files out of thousands of files in a directory in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have to load only those files from a directory which matches certain pattern to run my spark job .
For example i have 5k text files in a directory that has below naming pattern

```
Fundamental.FinancialLineItem.FinancialLineItem.Japan.BAL.1.2018-04-12-0542.Full
Fundamental.FinancialLineItem.FinancialLineItem.Japan.BUS.1.2018-04-12-0542.Full
Fundamental.FinancialLineItem.FinancialLineItem.SelfSourcedPrivate.SHE.1.2018-04-12-0542.Full
Fundamental.FinancialLineItem.FinancialLineItem.SelfSourcedPublic.PEN.1.2018-04-12-0542.Full

Fundamental.FinancialLineItem.Segments.Japan.1.2018-04-12-0542.Full
Fundamental.FinancialPeriod.FinancialPeriod.Japan.2018.1.2018-04-16-0348.Full
Fundamental.FinancialPeriod.Interim2Annual.Japan.1970.1.2018-04-13-0732.Full
```

Like this i have 5k text files in a directory .
In my spark job i have to load only file which has `FinancialLineItem` at third position from left to right  if we split name of the file with `"."`. 
So in that way only first 4 files will get loaded .

Id there anyway to load only that file .If i provide dir name in the `sc.TextFile()` then full directory will be loaded and that will take lots of space .
Currently i am loading files like this

```
//Loading main file
val rdd = sc.textFile(mainFileURL)
//val rdd =sc.wholeTextFiles(mainFileURL).filter(x => x._1.contains("FinancialLineItem")).flatMap(_._2.split("\n"))
//val rdd =sc.wholeTextFiles(mainFileURL).filter(x => Try(x._1.split("/").last.split("\\.")(2)).getOrElse("").equals("FinancialLineItem")).flatMap(_._2.split("\n"))
val header = rdd.filter(_.contains("LineItem.organizationId")).map(line => line.split("\\|\\^\\|")).first()
val schema = StructType(header.map(cols => StructField(cols.replace(".", "_"), StringType)).toSeq)
val data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd.filter(!_.contains("LineItem.organizationId")).map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split("\\|\\^\\|").toSeq)), schema)
val get_cus_val = sqlContext.udf.register("get_cus_val", (filePath: String) => filePath.split("\\.")(3))
val df1resultFinal = data.withColumn("DataPartition", get_cus_val(input_file_name))
val dataMain = df1resultFinal.withColumn("TimeStamp", lit(null: String))
```

mainFileURL is my directory name .

Comment: if you wanted to pass such file names with prerequisite option  like FinancialLineItem  at third position the you can get the file name and create LIST and pass that List to your Spark programme. It will work as input for spark program

Comment: @IndrajitSwain How can i get the file name without loading the folders . one sample example please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use glob pattern to define input. With `Dataset`

```
spark.read.text(
  s"${mainFileURL}/Fundamental.FinancialLineItem.FinancialLineItem*"
)
```

With `RDD`:

```
spark.sparkContext.textFile(
  s"${mainFileURL}/Fundamental.FinancialLineItem.FinancialLineItem*"
)
```

This way you'll only scan the file system, and avoid loading whole data (as it happens with `wholeTextFiles`).

Comment: Perfect...Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out your file names using [sc.wholeTextFiles](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#wholeTextFiles-java.lang.String-int-). Use below code for the desired result.

```
sc.wholeTextFiles(mainFileURL).filter(x => Try(x._1.split("/").last.split("\\.")(2)).getOrElse("").equals("FinancialLineItem")).flatMap(_._2.split("\n"))
```

Comment: Getting the same error ...It is loading Other files also and that is why join are failing ..When i remove and load only required file it runs good ...

Comment: You only want to load the files that has `FinancialLineItem` in third position (after `.`) right? above code should work for this case.

Comment: Yes ..But i have total 7 files in my dir ..When i run spark job i get spark logs as total input path to load 7 .I should get only 4 ..Also can you tell me will it load all files first and then will filter only 4 ?If thats the case then it will take more memory ..

Comment: Not sure why it is not working for you. For me its loading files as per your requirement. what is the value of `mainFileURL`?

Comment: Also in the spark logs shows name of all the files in that directory but it will process the files as per filter condition.

Comment: I have given path as `C://Users//use//Desktop//SPARK//trfsmallfffile//FinanicalLineItem//MAIN`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169230/discussion-between-vindev-and-anupam).